# Modernizr.load (yepnope.js) IE conditional confusion

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

In the following code `dd_belatedpng.js` is loading despite the fact that I'm using Firefox 4.0.1. According to [the yepnope.js documentation](http://yepnopejs.com/), the `ielt7!` prefix should cause the script only to load if the browser is IE less than version 7. Is this functionality removed from the Modernizr.load implementation (I believed that one was just an alias for the other), or a bug, or, as I suspect, me just missing/misunderstanding something obvious? Thanks for your help. Here's the code.

```
Modernizr.load([
    {   
        load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js',
        complete: function() {
            if(!window.jQuery) {
                Modernizr.load('/inc/jquery-1.6.1.min.js');
            }   
        }   
    },  
    {   
        load : 'ielt7!/inc/dd_belatedpng.js',
        callback: function() {
            $(function() {
                DD_belatedPNG.fix("img, .png_bg");
            }); 
        }   
    }/*,
    'jquery.plugins.js',
    'my.scripts.js'*/
]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably forgot to include [the `yepnope.ie-prefix.js` file](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/prefixes/yepnope.ie-prefix.js).

Comment: You're a star, thanks. I was scratching my head over this for a while. Is it just me though or is there no mention of needing (or link to) this on the yepnope.js site. Strange, but problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing! They don't mention it at all in the documentation nor is there much info out on the internets.